# Water heater pilot tube keeps getting condensation in it

Tags: water, heater

I have take line loose a couple times to blow it out but the condensation keeps coming back and causing the pilot light to go out...it does stay lit for a while after I clear the condensation...maybe a day or so

Comment: Actually likely not condensation in the usual sense but water vapor from the gas burning. But either way, that is a problem. How old is the water heater? What model?

Comment: Please post pictures of the heater label, and model.

Comment: It does not have a thermocouple it is a thermopile

Comment: Model number is n40t61-343 whirlpool 40 gallon

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you need a drip leg. A drip leg is usually installed after the local shutoff valve it is a simple T with a 6" or longer nipple that is capped pointing down. With a drip leg the moisture and some rust fall into the nipple, I have had a home that I had to clean the drip leg every year, others never needed cleaning 1 drop of water in your gas valve or pilot is enough to cause problems and a 6" drip leg is usually enough for most homes.

Comment: Great answer. About drip leg. A pic would help here.

Answer (score 0):

The condensation likely appears after the flame goes out.  Burning of gas produces water.

Every few years with a gas water heater it's necessary to replace the thermocouple.  The thermocouple is heated by the gas flame which produces a small electrical signal.  If that signal is lost the heater goes out.

[image]

Comment: I think it has a thermopile and not a thermocouple...if that is correct way to say it